# How to apply 10% discount on grand total price on cart page Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1. I want to give 10 % discount on grand total price in cart page for specific users and will show in cart page, order review page and in admin panel as well.

I follow the apply discount coupon thoroughly but unable to do that. I searched in Google but didn't fill my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magento coupon only.
Just login to the admin panel 
1) Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules 
2) Add New
3) Actions 
4) Apply -> Percent of product price discount

Its done.